# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=13

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create an Objective-C class for storing int arrays dynamically (just for the fun of it) but I am getting errors that says 'Error code=13' from running this class. Below are my class interface and implementation.

The interface section

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AsIntArray : NSObject

- ( id ) initWithSize: ( unsigned int ) initialSize;

- ( id ) initWithSize:( unsigned int ) initialSize andDefaultValue: ( int ) defaultVal;

- ( unsigned int ) size;
- ( int ) itemAtIndex: ( unsigned int ) index;
- ( void ) setItemAtIndex: ( unsigned int ) index andValue: ( int ) newValue;

- ( void ) clear;
- ( void ) addItem: ( int ) itemToAdd;
- ( void ) removeItemAtIndex: ( unsigned int ) index;

- ( NSString * ) toString;

@end
```

The implementation section

```
#import "AsIntArray.h"

@implementation AsIntArray  {
    unsigned int _uint_size;
    int *_int_array;
}

- ( id ) init   {
    self = [ super init ];
    if( self )  {
        _uint_size = 0;
        _int_array = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- ( id ) initWithSize:(unsigned int)initialSize {
    self = [ super init ];
    if( self )  {
        _uint_size = ( initialSize > 0 ? initialSize : 0 );
        if( _uint_size > 0 )    {
            _int_array = ( int * ) malloc( _uint_size );
        } else {
            _int_array = nil;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- ( id ) initWithSize:(unsigned int)initialSize andDefaultValue:(int)defaultVal {
    self = [ super init ];
    if( self )  {
        _uint_size = ( initialSize > 0 ? initialSize : 0 );
        if( _uint_size > 0 )    {
            _int_array = ( int * ) malloc( _uint_size );
            for( int i = 0; i < _uint_size; i++ )
                _int_array[ i ] = defaultVal;
        } else {
            _int_array = nil;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- ( unsigned int ) size { return _uint_size; }

- ( int ) itemAtIndex:(unsigned int)index   {
    return ( index < _uint_size ? _int_array[ index ] : 0 );
}

- ( void ) setItemAtIndex:(unsigned int)index andValue:(int)newValue    {
    if( index < _uint_size )    {
        _int_array[ index ] = newValue;
    }
}

- ( void ) clear    {
    if( _uint_size > 0 )    {
        _uint_size = 0;
        free( _int_array );
        _int_array = nil;
    }
}

- ( void ) addItem:(int)itemToAdd   {
    if( _uint_size == 0 )   {
        _uint_size++;
        _int_array = ( int * ) malloc( _uint_size );
        _int_array[ 0 ] = itemToAdd;
    } else  {
        int *temp = ( int * ) malloc( _uint_size );
        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < _uint_size; i++ )
            temp[ i ] = _int_array[ i ];

        free( _int_array );
        _int_array = nil;
        _uint_size++;
        _int_array = ( int * ) malloc( _uint_size );

        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < _uint_size - 1; i++ )
            _int_array[ i ] = temp[ i ];
        _int_array[ _uint_size - 1 ] = itemToAdd;

        free( temp );
        temp = nil;
    }
}

- ( void ) removeItemAtIndex:(unsigned int)index    {
    if( index < _uint_size )    {
        if( _uint_size <= 1 )   {
            [ self clear ];
        } else  {
            int *temp = ( int * ) malloc( _uint_size );
            for( unsigned int i = 0; i < _uint_size; i++ )
                temp[ i ] = _int_array[ i ];

            free( _int_array );
            _int_array = nil;
            _uint_size--;
            _int_array = ( int * ) malloc( _uint_size );

            unsigned int counter = 0;
            for( unsigned int i = 0; i <= _uint_size; i++ ) {
                if( i != index )    {
                    _int_array[ counter ] = temp[ i ];
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            free( temp );
            temp = nil;
        }
    }
}

//  Throws error code=13
/*- ( NSString * ) description    {
    NSMutableString *desc = [ [ NSMutableString alloc ] initWithString:@"{ " ];

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < _uint_size; i++ )  {
        if( i > 0 ) [ desc appendString:@", " ];
        [ desc appendFormat:@"%i", _int_array[ i ] ];
    }
    [ desc appendString:@" }" ];

    return [ desc description ];
}*/

- ( NSString * ) toString   {
    NSMutableString *desc = [ [ NSMutableString alloc ] initWithString:@"{ " ];

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < _uint_size; i++ )  {
        if( i > 0 ) [ desc appendString:@", " ];
        [ desc appendFormat:@"%i", _int_array[ i ] ];
    }
    [ desc appendString:@" }" ];

    return [ desc description ];
}

@end
```

And every time the error occurs, it always occur in the - ( NSString * ) description method. The output windows says: "objc[947]: *** hashtable: count differs after rehashing; probably indicates a broken invariant: there are x and y such as isEqual(x, y) is TRUE but hash(x) != hash(y)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size you're passing to malloc() is wrong. The argument to malloc is the size in *bytes*, but your integers are larger than one byte, so your array is only a fraction of the size it needs to be (probably only 25%!) and the rest of the memory you write to via the array pointer is somebody else's space you're scribbling over. Instead, you want to do `malloc(sizeof(int) * _uint_size)`.

Comment: Thank you! I guess this solved it for me. It didn't occur to me that I would have to specify number of bytes instead but I was thinking since that the malloc was created using size of the byte instead, is _int_arr[ _uint_size - 1 ] still valid?

Comment: @AlexSu: Yes, if you create an array the way I said, it will allocate enough memory to hold `_uint_size` integers.

Comment: Thanks again! Guess I was so used to specifying "new int[ _uint_size ]" as in C++!

Comment: @AlexSu: Yeah. The difference is that C++'s new operator actually knows the type of the array you're creating, so it can figure out how much memory you need for however many items, while malloc() is just a dumb memory allocator function that knows nothing about what the memory will be used for.

Comment: Okay. I will be more careful when using malloc in the future in either C or Objective-C. I guess both 'new' and 'malloc' has its own pros and cons...